# Testing combobox developed using ExtJS with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, css-selectors, casperjs, browser-testing

I have developed my application using ExtJs 4.1. I have a combobox which gets populated using Ajax call. Once the comobox is populated, I need to find an item by name and then first the select event for that item.

The problem is the way combo-box is rendered by ExtJS. I am not sure how to select an item in the right manner. CombBox is not really a `<select>` element but a `text input` with a detached drop-down list that's somewhere at the bottom of the document tree.

I do not want to hard code the id's as ExtJS randomly generate the id.

This is how the generated HTML looks

[image]

You can check the example of ExtJs combobox [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1-pr1/docs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox)

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, I would suggest,

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;

casper.thenClick(".x-form-trigger.x-form-arrow-trigger")
    .wait(100)
    .thenClick(x("//li[contains(@class,'x-boundlist-item') and contains(text(),'Alaska')]"))
    .wait(100, function(){
        this.capture("screenshot.png");
    });
```

You might also need to move the mouse into position before clicking. Use

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.mouse.move(selector)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the ComboBox in a **form**, you could use the ***"name"* property** in the ComboBox definition and select it with:

```
Ext.getCmp("idOfThePanel").down('form').getForm().findField('name');
```

Another option, use the ***"reference"* property**. In this case I'm not sure which is the correct way to select the ComoBox:

```
Ext.getCmp("idOfThePanel").down('form').getForm().lookupReference('reference');
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp("idOfThePanel").lookupReference('reference');
```

Comment: This is how I have included extjs. `casperjs test --include=ext-all.js testFile.js`. After Including the ext reference, I am able to say `var component = Ext.getCmp('component-id')`. But  `component` remains `undefined`.